# What is this (possibly WW1) officer's uniform and regiment?

Tags: world-war-one, uniform

This photograph comes from an old family photo album - our family is of British descent who lived in South Africa.  Unfortunately those who knew this person have since died and we are hoping to track down who he was.  We suspect the uniform is WW1 but were wondering if it might be older.  Apologies that I can't provide any further details.  Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.[image: Officer in uniform - possibly WW1]

Comment: A verbose visual description is needed for search engines and the visually impaired. Wikipedia’s advice on visual descriptions, or previous well described uniform questions should provide a model. (Close: Insufficient detail)

Comment: Consider the verbose visual description in this question as a model: https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/61249/identify-regiment-of-1826-1861-french-cuirass-cavalry-uniform

Comment: My purely gut feeling is around the Boer Wars, although I'm on a phone so detail is difficult. The Sam Browne belt would seem to date it from turn of the century, not earlier. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sam_Browne_belt